# Getting error with gRPC ruby / python client

Tags: python, ruby, grpc

Following is my protobuf defition:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package hello;

service HelloService {
    rpc SayHello(HelloReq) returns (HelloResp) {};
    rpc SayHelloStrict(HelloReq) returns (HelloResp) {};
}

message HelloReq {
    string Name = 1;
}

message HelloResp {
    string Result = 1;
}
```

My Ruby server:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

this_dir = File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))
lib_dir = File.join(this_dir, 'lib')
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(lib_dir) unless $LOAD_PATH.include?(lib_dir)

require 'grpc'
require 'hello_services_pb'

class HelloServer < Hello::HelloService::Service

  def say_hello(hello_req, _unused_call)
    Hello::HelloResp.new(result: "Hey #{hello_req.name}")
  end

  def say_hello_strict(hello_req, _unused_call)
    Hello::HelloResp.new(result: "Hey #{hello_req.name}")
  end

end

def main
  s = GRPC::RpcServer.new
  s.add_http2_port('0.0.0.0:50051', :this_port_is_insecure)
  s.handle(HelloServer)
  s.run_till_terminated
end

main
```

My Ruby client:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

this_dir = File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))
lib_dir = File.join(this_dir, 'lib')
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(lib_dir) unless $LOAD_PATH.include?(lib_dir)

require 'grpc'
require 'hello_services_pb'

def main
  stub = Hello::HelloService::Stub.new('localhost:50051', :this_channel_is_insecure)
  message = stub.say_hello(Hello::HelloReq.new(name: "Euler")).result
  p "Greeting: #{message}"
end

main
```

when I run, I get following error:

```
client.rb:12:in `initialize': Unknown field name 'name' in initialization map entry. (ArgumentError)
  from client.rb:12:in `new'
  from client.rb:12:in `main'
  from client.rb:16:in `<main>'
```

I wrote a Python client too to test and I get an error here too:

```
import grpc

import hello_pb2
import hello_pb2_grpc


def run():
    channel = grpc.insecure_channel('localhost:50051')
    stub = hello_pb2_grpc.HelloServiceStub(channel)
    response = stub.SayHello(hello_pb2.HelloReq(Name='Euler'))
    print(response.Result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

And the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 38, in <module>
    run()
  File "client.py", line 11, in run
    response = stub.SayHello(hello_pb2.HelloReq(Name='Euler'))
  File "/Users/avi/.virtualenvs/grpc-errors/lib/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 507, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, deadline)
  File "/Users/avi/.virtualenvs/grpc-errors/lib/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 455, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _Rendezvous(state, None, None, deadline)
grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with (StatusCode.UNKNOWN, NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for <Hello::HelloReq: Name: "Euler">:Hello::HelloReq)>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is due to the capitalized "Name" field in the proto file, being referred to as lowercase "name" in the code. The generated proto code's accessor is in the same case as the

Answer (score 0):

> It looks like this is due to the capitalized "Name" field in the proto 
>   file, being referred to as lowercase "name" in the code. The generated
>   proto code's accessor is in the same case as the

Sorry for the cut sentence in the above comment ^.

Meant to say: *The generated proto code's accessor is in the same case as it's defined in the .proto file.